Override the accounts/login/ in Django
So I'm using django.contrib.auth.urls and I would prefer to continue that.
But I want the accounts/login url to be replaced with users/c-login or whatever.
I would really like to understand why this is not working:
my urls.py (project):
from core import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("", include("core.urls")),
    path("user/", include("user.urls")),
    path("accounts/login", views.atest, name="login"),
    path("accounts/login/", views.atest, name="login"),
]

The idea here was that
path("accounts/login/", views.atest, name="login"),

should "replace" the django auth urls.
views.py user app:
def atest(request):
    return redirect("c-login")


And the custom login views.py user app:
def custom_login(request):
    template_name = "registration/login.html"


Any help appreciated. Thanks

Django looks at your url patterns in order until it finds one that matches, so path("accounts/login", views.atest, name="login") will not ever be seen because path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")) matches first.  Having said that, if all you want to do is create a user registration page, or style the login page, then you don't need this.  Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication (especially https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication#setting_up_your_authentication_views)

I knew that :) !! But I was so far into this mess with redirecting and login vews that I forgot! Ended up doing it totally different and so much easier. But still needed to know about the order of the Urls. So thanks a lot.

Comment from raphael answers the question 100%!
Django looks at your url patterns in order until it finds one that matches, so path("accounts/login", views.atest, name="login") will not ever be seen because path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")) matches first. Having said that, if all you want to do is create a user registration page, or style the login page, then you don't need this.
Check out developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/… (especially developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/…) –
